# face detection with augemented reality c++

Tags: c++, augmented-reality, face-detection

I want to develop an app for windows in which the user's face will be detected with opencv and after the detection I want to display an AR 3d object on a specific area of the detected face. Could you please suggest me a nice tutorial? Or at least explain how augemented reality can "see" this area I want?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [nice tutorial and the source code](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html?highlight=face%20detect) for face detection at OpenCV documentation.

Then you can simply place your AR object on some specified region inside the circle drawn by the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much! I suppose I have to use artoolkit and opengl for this. Am I right?

Comment: As far as I know, opengl is a must for creating 3d images. ARtoolkit is for calibration and tracking purposes. It depends on your application. For example, if you need your 3D object to be smaller when the face is far away, you need artoolkit.